# My android emulator in eclipse, does not start

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

i have this problem:
when i try start my emulator in eclipse i wait 15 minutes and it is not started. 
I try reinstall eclipse but emulator still dont working.

```
03-19 15:26:38.960: E/Installer(438): connection failed
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438): ******************************************
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438): ************ Failure starting bootstrap service
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438):  at com.android.server.firewall.IntentFirewall.readRulesDir(IntentFirewall.java:271)
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438):  at com.android.server.firewall.IntentFirewall.<init>(IntentFirewall.java:114)
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.main(ActivityManagerService.java:1804)
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:196)
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438):  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1179)
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-19 15:26:39.530: E/System(438):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438): *** FATAL EXCEPTION IN SYSTEM PROCESS: WindowManager
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.server.display.LocalDisplayAdapter$LocalDisplayDevice.getDisplayDeviceInfoLocked(LocalDisplayAdapter.java:147)
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.handleDisplayDeviceAddedLocked(DisplayManagerService.java:852)
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.handleDisplayDeviceAdded(DisplayManagerService.java:841)
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService.access$1100(DisplayManagerService.java:96)
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.server.display.DisplayManagerService$DisplayAdapterListener.onDisplayDeviceEvent(DisplayManagerService.java:1281)
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.server.display.DisplayAdapter$1.run(DisplayAdapter.java:108)
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-19 15:26:39.630: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
03-19 15:26:39.640: E/AndroidRuntime(438): Error reporting crash
03-19 15:26:39.640: E/AndroidRuntime(438): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 15:26:39.640: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException(RuntimeInit.java:84)
03-19 15:26:39.640: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:693)
03-19 15:26:39.640: E/AndroidRuntime(438):  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException(ThreadGroup.java:690)
03-19 15:27:46.600: E/Installer(796): connection failed
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796): ******************************************
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796): ************ Failure starting bootstrap service
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796):  at com.android.server.firewall.IntentFirewall.readRulesDir(IntentFirewall.java:271)
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796):  at com.android.server.firewall.IntentFirewall.<init>(IntentFirewall.java:114)
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.main(ActivityManagerService.java:1804)
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.initAndLoop(SystemServer.java:196)
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796):  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1179)
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-19 15:27:47.120: E/System(796):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I install eclipse with adt with sdk for android and i can not start emulator.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening emulator with less device screen size like 3.2'and wait for emulator to launch,on first occasion it might take some time.
 Emulator with high config and screen size takes ages to open and sometimes does not even launch no matter what.
 I had the same problem and i opened emulator using small screen resolution and boom it worked. :) Try it.

Comment: Please read this article: http://simonguest.com/2013/04/16/enabling-x86-android-emulation/ you can speed up your emulator and testing your application on the all screen resolutions!